# How can I remove the landscape.canonical.com greeting from motd?

Tags: landscape

Logging into a server with ssh produces the landscape-generated message of the day, which includes the suggestion for using https://landscape.canonical.com/ to graph data:

```
  Graph this data and manage this system at https://landscape.canonical.com/
```

How can I trim this or other lines from the ssh greeting?  With legal boilerplate added to the login banner already, I'd like to keep some information from landscape-sysinfo, but see less of it.

Answer (score 14):

To remove the `landscape.canonical.com` line, create or edit (as root) the file `/etc/landscape/client.conf`.

In `/etc/landscape/client.conf`, add these lines:

```
[sysinfo]
exclude_sysinfo_plugins = LandscapeLink
```

This works for all default plugins:

```
 Load, Disk, Memory, Temperature, Processes, LoggedInUsers, LandscapeLink, Network
```

So, to have your motd look more like this :

```
  System load:  0.83                Swap usage:          0%
  Usage of /:   59.5% of 117.38GB   Users logged in:     3
  Memory usage: 7%                  IP address for eth0: 10.10.30.70
```

...you would want to remove `Temperature`, `LandscapeLink`, `Processes` from the landscape-sysinfo process.

These can be added in the client.conf file as before, comma separated:

```
[sysinfo]
exclude_sysinfo_plugins = LandscapeLink,Temperature,Processes
```

This can be tested one the command line with:

`landscape-sysinfo  --exclude-sysinfo-plugins=Temperature,LandscapeLink,Processes`

See `landscape-sysinfo --help` for some additional information.

Comment: `/etc/landscape/client.conf` should be owned by `landscape` user for settings to take effect. Confirmed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1066115

Comment: Not only does /etc/landscape/client.conf have be owned by user landscape, it should also belong to group landscape. sudo chown landscape:landscape /etc/landscape/client.conf did the trick.